# The multi-part identifier "tst.ID" could not be bound

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this SQL Server query:

```
INSERT INTO "ROLES" ("ID", "NAME", "IS_ACTIVE", "MOD_USER_ID", "MOD_TIME", "NAME_EN") 
    SELECT 'Admin', 'Administrator', 0, 'ModUser', GETDATE(), 'Administrator' 
    WHERE tst."ID" is NULL

INSERT INTO "PERMISSIONS" ("ROLE_ID", "PERMISSION_ID") 
    SELECT 'ROLEID' AS "ROLE_ID", perm."ID" AS "PERMISSION_ID" 
    FROM "PERMISSION_DICT" perm 
    LEFT JOIN "PERMISSIONS" tst ON tst."PERMISSION_ID" = perm."ID" 
                                AND tst."ROLE_ID" = 'ROLEID' 
    WHERE tst."PERMISSION_ID" IS NULL
```

But when executing I get an error which says

> The multi-part identifier "tst.ID" could not be bound.

How do I fix that?

Comment: Make life easier - don't use double quotes (or square brackets) without a good reason. Those just make your code more difficult to read. If you follow the rules for regular identifiers, you don't need them.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting that error because you are using the column `"tst.ID"` in `Where` clause without using the table name, as the `From` clause in your first query is missing :

```
SELECT 'Admin', 'Administrator', 0, 'ModUser', GETDATE(), 'Administrator' 
WHERE tst."ID" is NULL
```

I assume it would be like this :

```
INSERT INTO "ROLES" ("ID", "NAME", "IS_ACTIVE", "MOD_USER_ID", "MOD_TIME", "NAME_EN") 
SELECT 'Admin', 'Administrator', 0, 'ModUser', GETDATE(), 'Administrator'
```